# Jquery validation not working in IE and Firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, http-status-code-404

I have jquery validation in jsp in my spring mvc application. I used `rules{required:true}` for validation of the fields which works fine for chrome but having problems in IE and firefox.

IE9: I get a pop-up at the bottom of my screen. If I say "show all content" the validation works.  If I do not click this button, I get the 404 error if I attempt to leave a field blank.

Firefox: I do not get any pop up at the bottom of my screen.  The validation does not work, I just get 404 error if something is left blank.

Please help if you can and Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This "show all content" message, does it say that some of the resources being requested are insecure? If so, then you're loading an HTTPS request with JS and other files being requested as HTTP, which makes for an insecure connection.

Are you specifying the protocol when loading your jQuery or jQuery Validate JS file? If so, you can replace `http://` with just `//` to have the JS file loaded using the protocol of the request.